# Mocking a promise, and testing 'setState' in '.then()'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing unit tests for a React application. A click-handler calls a simple promise, and updates the state inside of '.then()'. I have successfully mocked the promise and am able to enter the correct if/else block using mock data returned from the resolved promise.

It seems that using a console.log to test the data shows that the data is partially incorrect. I'm also unable to test that the state has changed, as (I suppose) setState is asynchronous.

I have tried using .update(), .forceUpdate(), setTimeout(), and setImmediate(). I'm not sure what else to try to be able to test that the state has changed correctly.

Here is the method being tested:

```
    this.handleClick = () => {
      sendMessage(this.urlParams.data1, this.urlParams.data2, this.urlParams.data3)
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.messageType === 'error') {
            console.log(data.message);
            this.setState({
              error: data.message,
            }, () => {
              console.log(data);
            });
          } else {
            this.doSomething();
          }
        });
    };
```

Here is the mock of the 'sendMessage' method, which is working as expected:

```
    export const sendPnrgovMessage = () => Promise.resolve({ data: { messageType: 'error', message: 'asdf' } });
```

Here is the test itself:

```
    it('should send the message when the button is clicked', () => {
      renderedInstance = rendered.instance();
      renderedInstance.handleClick();
      renderedInstance.forceUpdate(() => {
        expect(rendered.state('error')).toEqual('asdf');
      });
    });
```

I've also tried without the '.forceUpdate()', the result is the same.

There are two issues with the result.

1.) 'data' in the '.then()' evaluates to this:

```
{ messageType: 'error', message: undefined }
```

Why would message be undefined, while messageType is correct?

2.) The expected value of this.state.error is 'asdf', or in the above case, 'undefined', but it is actually 'null', which is the initialized value. I assumed that this is because setState is asynchronous and is not being updated by the time the test has finished. I have not found a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mocking the function implementation using `jest`?

```
import { sendMessage } from './file';

describe('should test component', () => {
   beforeAll(() => {
      sendMessage = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: { message, Type: 'error', message: 'asdf' } });
   });
   afterAll(() => sendMessage.mockRestore());

   it('should send the message when the button is clicked', () => {
      renderedInstance = rendered.instance();
      renderedInstance.handleClick();
      renderedInstance.forceUpdate(() => {
         expect(rendered.state('error')).toEqual('asdf');
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You made 2 mistakes in your code.

- The return value of sendMessage is { data: { messageType: 'error', message: 'asdf' } }
  so you should receive the message as {data}. curly brack is required.
- When we use the arrow function, we must avoid the 'this' context because it doesn't bind own this.

The answer is as follows:

```
this.handleClick = () => {
  const ref = this;
  sendMessage(this.urlParams.data1, this.urlParams.data2, this.urlParams.data3)
    .then(({data}) => {
      if (data.messageType === 'error') {
        console.log(data.message);
        ref.setState({
          error: data.message,
        }, () => {
          console.log(data);
        });
      } else {
        ref .doSomething();
      }
    });
};
```